# Worksheet_Change with manual calculation (Application.Calculation = xlManual)

Tags: vba, excel

I want Excel to calculate the sheet, every time the user enters a value ([source1](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4423-excel-run-macro-on-cell-change.html) [source2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Worksheet("Calc").Range("R1:R100")

    MsgBox "Check!"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

       ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been changed.
       MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
       'Calculate
       Sheets("Calc").Calculate
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The sheet does not get recalculated after entry of value. Even, the message box "Check!" never appears. - Why is that?

---

(For info: I can only guess that it has something to do with my setting the calculation to "manual":
I have a sheet in Workbook "B.xlsm" with circular references, hence I run a script from Workbook "A.xlsm", from where I open Workbook "B.xlsm":

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
[...]
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
```

Is there a way to get this method "Change" to work with manual calculation?)

Comment: Worksheet_Change has nothing to with calculation. It is triggered by changes in hard-coded values, not the results from formulas.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change.aspx), "This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation". Take a look at [Worksheet.Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.calculate.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but it's not working nevertheless. So, there must be something that prevents the script from running, ...

Comment: To make the Worksheet_Change event fire, you need to enter a value in a cell and then press enter or tab.

One more thing, make sure your Worksheet_Change event is in the correct sheet module.

Comment: So it isn't firing for *user* interactions in the cell?

Comment: Maybe you turned off events without turning them back on?  That can happen if your code errors out midway.  Paste `Application.EnableEvents = True` into the Immediate pane and hit enter to make sure event handling is turned on.

Comment: No, it's not firing. 
`msgbox Application.EnableEvents` returns `True`

Comment: Is this code in the *worksheet* code module, or in a regular module?  Right-click the sheet tab >> View Code

Answer (score 3):

I think Tim nailed it.

At some point in testing the code, the code stopped;  Either from and Run-time Error or manually stepping through line-by-line.  In either case, you probably changed something which forced it to reset and it never had a chance to run the most important line...`Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Disabling Events is a persistent state.

It's very wise to make sure that you have error handling working to restore it, if other users are going to be using your code.  Unfortunately, you'll still break it while testing.

I use the following routine (at the top of the main module) to fix it, when this happens:

```
Public Sub FixIt()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In fact, I usually call this routine as the first line of any button I have on the Ribbon/Sheet, just to make sure that everything is working like it should be.

In your case, you could omit the `Application.Calculation` line, or set it equal to `xlManual`